# Where to put helper module on Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to add a helper module to  do a get request using

http://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/HTTPoison.Base.html

But when I put the `defmodule` in

> /lib/Shopper/CallApi.ex

and `use` in

> /web.ex

```
def controller do
quote do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  alias Shopper.Repo
  import Ecto.Model
  import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 1, from: 2]

  import Shopper.Router.Helpers

  use Shopper.CallApi
end
```

end

the compiler failed with

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/page_controller.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Shopper.CallApi.__using__/1
    Shopper.CallApi.__using__([])
    web/controllers/page_controller.ex:2: (module)
```

So... Where to define CallApi.ex and where I should declare it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `use Shopper.CallApi`, `__using__/1` macro is called - this is specific to meta-programming. If you want to use functions defined in `Shopper.CallApi` in your module then use `alias Shopper.CallApi` instead.

The differences between `alias`, `require` and `import` are documented in [Alias, Require and Import](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html) and `using` is documented in [Domain Specific Languages](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/domain-specific-languages.html#storing-information-with-attributes).

As an aside, normally in elixir projects, files are named in snake_case - `call_api.ex` instead of `CallApi.ex`.

Comment: and.. I don't think the `use` documentation is clear enough for beginner like me

Comment: For the filename, it's already in form of xxxx_api.ex, but I need to remove the xxxx part. Just bad editing :)